# When redemption.dll is loaded and operational excel 2016 pauses before launching saved files from disk

Tags: excel, outlook-redemption

I have identified a possible issue with redemption slowing down excel when you click a file from disk (with excel closed), it introduces a delay of minimum 4-5 seconds.

If excel is open the files open immediately from disk, the problem goes away when we close the program that has launched the redemption.dll process is closed.

If you launch excel via the command line with the file as an argument then it also launches immediately eg. "c:\path to office\excel.exe" myfile.xls its jsut if you click it then there is a pause.

**All the important helpful bits**

- Machine is a 2016 RDS Host (Latest patches (inc Jan 2020 patch)), 8
  cores, 16GB Memory, users and admins are affected (tested multiple
  accounts)
- Office is 2016 standard edition with all items installed (again fully patched)
- Redemption.dll version is 5.20.0.5298

I have tried just de-registering the redemption.dll but I suspect the program that launches it looks where it expects to find it within its world, and re-registers it (kind of expected tbh), if I de-register it and delete the dll from disk then the program falls back to the outlook security triggering tick the box method but excel does not get slowed down at all when launching files with excel closed.

Side note: Word is unaffected

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue turned out to be a setting within the software thats using redemption, something calander related as the setting we altered to resolve the issue related to diary monitoring.

Thanks.